# GSON - Creating JSON string from Object and viseversa

Tags: json, gson

I've a simple object like this

```
public class WebMessage
{
    public String destinationAddress;
    public String clientType;
    public JsonObject params;
}
```

When i want to create a JSON string from this object using GSON i do it like the following:

```
WebMessage parringMsg = new WebMessage();
JsonObject parameters = new JsonObject();
parameters.addProperty("action", "PARRING_START");        
parringMsg.params = parameters;        

String finalString = jsonString.toJson(parringMsg);
```

But final string looks like this:

```
{"params":{"members":{"action":"PARRING_START"}}}
```

I dont understand why my action key is placed inside a members key. Why is that?

I want it to look like this:

```
{"params":{"action":"PARRING_START"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a JSONObject inside my Class i used a HashMap like so:

```
public class WebMessage
{
    public WebMessage()
    {
        params = new HashMap<>();
    }    
    public String destinationAddress;
    public String clientType;    
    public HashMap<String,String> params;   
}
```

Then i could simply put values in there like this, which is also much simpler:

```
WebMessage parringMsg = new WebMessage();
parringMsg.params.put("action", "PARRING_START");
String finalString = jsonString.toJson(parringMsg);
```

With the above i get the desired output in finalString:

```
{"params":{"action":"PARRING_START"}}
```